# Check python module version with ansible

Tags: python, pip, ansible

Is there any way to create ansible playbook that finds out what version of python module is currently installed on destination host? I don't want to install specified version, I just want to know if it is present or not (example responses `module installed: version 12.03` or `module not installed`)

With `pip` ansible module I found, that there is no state to ensure if something is installed, only possibilities is to install or remove

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: For example to print stats or check if I can run some script on this machine. In fact, I just want to know if something like this is possible with ansible

Comment: But it's not how you should manage systems. It's not the system who determines what you can do. It's you who defines what the system is and what you can do.

Comment: So, in other words, ansible isn't tool to check if something exists, but to make sure that something exists or not (by installing it or removing). Only checking is not possible, right?

Comment: No. I mean you shouldn't do it. If you answered you needed to verify, or prove compliance, I would advise using Serverspec or testinfra. But since you want to submit yourself, you need to wait for someone else to answer. I'm not going to help you become a slave to a version of some software module installed somewhere.

Comment: In fact, I only want to know if python module is available on some machine. Getting version is only additional thing, it's good to know how to check it

Comment: Maybe run Ansible in check mode.

Answer (score 3):

How about this for POSIX systems?

```
- name: check version of pytz
  shell: pip show pytz | grep Version | cut -d ' ' -f 2
  ignore_errors: true
  changed_when: false
  register: pytz_version
```

To just print the module version:

```
- debug: var=pytz_version.stdout
```

You can also use the version as a 'when' clause in other tasks:

```
- name: Do something requiring pytz 2012d
  command: foo
  when: pytz_version.stdout | search("2012d")
```

Comment: What if pip and the package are in a venv?